# Can I cache/resume a rolling window operation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a pd.Series.rolling() operation executed on a DataFrame.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

def rnd_walk(n):
    x = 0
    for i in range(n):
        r = random.random()
        if r > 0.5:
            x =+ random.random()
        else:
            x -= random.random()
        yield x

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA':list(rnd_walk(100))})

df['SMA_7'] = df.DATA.rolling(window=7).mean()


df.tail(10)
    DATA    SMA_7
90  0.143081    0.204043
91  -0.624594   0.231501
92  0.457923    0.275728
93  0.210151    0.223075
94  0.234321    0.163321
95  -0.218407   0.128217
96  -0.978240   -0.110824
97  0.045524    -0.124760
98  0.151820    -0.013844
99  0.036074    -0.074108
```

After that, I need to add some extra rows to the DataFrame.

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'DATA':list(rnd_walk(5))})).reset_index(drop=True)
df.tail(10)
    DATA    SMA_7
95  -0.218407   0.128217
96  -0.978240   -0.110824
97  0.045524    -0.124760
98  0.151820    -0.013844
99  0.036074    -0.074108
100 -0.089913   NaN
101 0.518280    NaN
102 0.205221    NaN
103 0.101302    NaN
104 0.309708    NaN
```

My question now is, how can I compute the `SMA_7` only for the last added values without repeating the calculation on the whole DataFrame? Is there a general way to cache the computation and resume it from row 99, i.e. without repeating any computation that has already been done previously?

Comment: create a stream of the list and take some batch size lets say 1000 batch. Now after each batch save into pickle object and continue. At the end append this list to dataframe.
Resume: if you want to resume then just read pickle ob and continue from last index

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh It would be more efficient to re-run the rolling computation on the whole dataframe at that point.

Comment: I am assuming you are working on billions of rows. So take batch size in 10^6 order. I am giving a solution for long computation, not a few million rows. If you use SIMD which pandas already use, it will be nearly efficient.

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh it's a few thousands of rows, not many, it is more of a general question, I wanted to know if there is a way to simply continue the computation from where it was left.

Comment: batch processing or chuck processing is the only as I know.